# In Postgresql memory space for some table unreal big

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 11.8. and after som time on test server I faced with strange behaviour. Simple query executed very slow ~ 1 minute. In locally with the simmilar data in row, becuase it was fill by the same algorithm, I faced with absolulty different result. Maybe because in test server once a day execute up script which update each row but.. count rows not growed, only updated data.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
53 **second**
293617 rows

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
sepnt 0.5 second
and 282796 rows
```

after check memory space

```
WITH RECURSIVE pg_inherit(inhrelid, inhparent) AS
    (select inhrelid, inhparent
    FROM pg_inherits
    UNION
    SELECT child.inhrelid, parent.inhparent
    FROM pg_inherit child, pg_inherits parent
    WHERE child.inhparent = parent.inhrelid),
pg_inherit_short AS (SELECT * FROM pg_inherit WHERE inhparent NOT IN (SELECT inhrelid FROM pg_inherit))
SELECT table_schema
    , TABLE_NAME
    , row_estimate
    , pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
  FROM (
    SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes
    FROM (
         SELECT c.oid
              , nspname AS table_schema
              , relname AS TABLE_NAME
              , SUM(c.reltuples) OVER (partition BY parent) AS row_estimate
              , SUM(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)) OVER (partition BY parent) AS total_bytes
              , SUM(pg_indexes_size(c.oid)) OVER (partition BY parent) AS index_bytes
              , SUM(pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid)) OVER (partition BY parent) AS toast_bytes
              , parent
          FROM (
                SELECT pg_class.oid
                    , reltuples
                    , relname
                    , relnamespace
                    , pg_class.reltoastrelid
                    , COALESCE(inhparent, pg_class.oid) parent
                FROM pg_class
                    LEFT JOIN pg_inherit_short ON inhrelid = oid
                WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'p')
             ) c
             LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  ) a
  WHERE oid = parent
) a
ORDER BY total_bytes DESC;
```

and faced with strage result on TABLE

locally

```
public  products    282871  1902 MB 832 MB  96 MB   974 MB
```

and on the test server

```
public  products    293771  16 GB   4979 MB 1090 MB 10 GB
```

why on test server 10GB how it's possible ?

For table products applied trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION products_ts_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.common_fts :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.name,'')), 'A') ||     
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.description,'')), 'B') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.price::text,'')), 'C') ||
         setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish', coalesce(new.brand,'')), 'D');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON products FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION products_ts_trigger();
```

but I tested it, `common_fts` not contain some duplictaed data.

I use alpine image with set `shm_size` and for db set `work_mem`, `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`, `max_connections`

```
   postgres:
        image: postgres:11-alpine
        command: postgres -c work_mem=5GB -c max_parallel_workers_per_gather=6 -c max_connections=400
        shm_size: 8g
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
        container_name: 'postgresql_alpine'
        working_dir: /app
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: minimoj
            POSTGRES_USER: minimoj
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: V9CNFPmymvQkCXvT
            LC_COLLATE: 'sv_SE.UTF-8'
            LC_CTYPE: 'sv_SE.UTF-8'
        volumes:
            - ./data/postgresql-dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./pg/thesaurus_my_swedish.ths:/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/thesaurus_my_swedish.ths
        networks:
            - php
```

maybe big `work_mem` did some effect for space and regarding this effect for speed query ...

But after I removed all images from server my disc space increase by Total reclaimed space: 6.023GB.

```
docker system prune -a --volumes

untagged: alpine:3.10
untagged: alpine@sha256:f0e9534a598e501320957059cb2a23774b4d4072e37c7b2cf7e95b241f019e35
untagged: postgres:11-alpine
untagged: postgres@sha256:fed26d3b33ed6c29437d1afaf483a60bf39c10f878e7ae5662436862e743e3b0
deleted: sha256:a7f73db0b9776fd8742765423f14c7d742440b0012dda2ad869cb8012e668dda
deleted: sha256:d1bdf897cb1b27f4767dee2c8a108128abe41320ccaa433ce7ed889ac29147a5
deleted: sha256:d64b58d01fcc17edb4f7b8f127f7b5caf4712b4dc69bb804bc8921388b2dc16e
deleted: sha256:f1b1ea2f2b9af94d56fa68104c40fac0348ed469838f5960fe7a5f4f8f50705a
deleted: sha256:4e0cd18892610356540afe6100b05d29b7ef8e387d311eff855e90d19742c387
deleted: sha256:39e10d4cad6705650333181aa15eee004b2d9fe9f0ee1676b01e8b60c97d4212
deleted: sha256:a5f1a1b618e561d7c5aae37552d14ea09d2d9886e59aefe50a6ef9e363c4e0b1
deleted: sha256:1546a64abdb698edf6075fc8f49d0fd9a87f4664ee11ef034c878234e39d1c08
deleted: sha256:496ffdcbe16b07bf705464ea386906752a410d72a417e292c6d2f148918e7bf6
....
deleted other images
....
Total reclaimed space: 3.774GB
```

Main question why after 7 days data base table increase to 10GB and query was very slow, simple count spent 53 seconds, with the same rows in table ?

How it's possible  pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE spent 10GB, but after removed all images freed 6GB?

And another strange behaviour, RAM on test server evrytime full more 50%, from 15 GB always full 13GB..

**UPDATE**
After I removed and rebuild all images and again executed parsing script I faced with this data on test server

query about space retunr result

```
                                    index  | toeast|table
public  products    267435  1165 MB 527 MB  61 MB   578 MB
```

and expected time spetn  for count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
278396
0.3second
```

Based on this, the conclusion suggests itself that some data duplicated and db table product memory increase and this is not common_fts column with type tsvector

Comment: How exactly did you "remove images" to free the space? Can we see the statements?

Comment: `docker system prune -a --volumes` I updated question

Comment: This is completely confusing. First there is a vague complaint that a table grows and scanning it gets slower after a lot of `UPDATE`s (which is not surprising), then you say that disk space is freed after you uninstall software.

Comment: I thing some problem with growing duplicate data. Maybe trigger for set ts vector data..

Comment: I tested it, trigger about set ts data on ts column not duplicated data. Main question why after 7 days data base table increase to 10GB and query was very slow, simple count spoent 53 seconds, with the same rows in table ?

Comment: Why this value `pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE` increase if table contain the same or small modify data after update each row, maybe ned provide some way for reset index or something ? Maybe this index contain some duplicated data ?

Comment: That is totally normal if you do a lot of updates, and autovacuum is not tuned aggressive enough to keep up.

Comment: Increase index amount and table can have been be normal process, but after 7 iteration, each time index increased on ~700mb and table amount increased on ~700 mb too and after that I faced with slow query for simple query like `COUNT`. What do you recomend how to optimization this trick ?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe `SET track_counts = on; SET autovacuum = on` ?

Comment: or maybe woud be better remove dead row manually like this `VACUUM (VERBOSE) products;`?

Comment: Don't do so many updates on the table.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe but this table contain products which parsing and saving by script in table from outside, from another resources, two time on day. Script automaticly up and will parse products again, for keep data in actual state. Would be correct if after each time when script finished I will execute `VACUUM (VERBOSE) products;` manually or I should set in on global conf  `SET track_counts = on; SET autovacuum = on` ?

Comment: I checked current state and faced with `select name, setting, unit, source from pg_settings where name = 'autovacuum'; select name, setting, unit, source from pg_settings where name = 'track_counts';` for both `setting` equal `on` .. What if I will execute `VACUUM (VERBOSE) products;` manually?